# Why apt-upgrade command didn't update PHP version?

Tags: 18.04, server, upgrade, updates, php

I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` command on ubuntu 18.04 server. When I checked the PHP version after, it was `PHP 5.6`. I don't remember the PHP version before upgrading the system (but I know the latest PHP stable release is 8.0). My question is why `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` didn't upgrade the PHP version?

Comment: Turn the question around: Why would `upgrade` bump a major release version within an Ubuntu release? That would cause all kinds of breakage. It would be a terrible mess. No Ubuntu system would be reliable if any random `upgrade` could break version-compatibility. Your phrasing of the question suggests that you perhaps don't realize that the entire OS is made up of packages, too -- it's a fragile structure. Substitute the wrong package and it all comes crashing down. So we don't do that.

Comment: Exactly; if you managed to upgrade php from 5.6 to 8.0 just as you described, you could take it for granted that more than half of the websites on the server would have crashed and became useless. Upgrading website source code for compatibility with so much higher php version could demand a significant effort. For this and other additional reasons people often rather opt for preparing a new backend for the website.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 ships PHP 7.2. You can find that out by searching the packages [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all).

But there is a PPA providing new PHP versions: [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

You may use that by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the desired php packages and versions. Best use `aptitude` and search for `php8`.

Answer (score 1):

You have likely installed a specific version of PHP, which is a different package from other versions of PHP. You likely had something like `php5.6`, but Ubuntu will not automatically upgrade to a different package. It just updates the installed packages, so you will need to install a different package, such as `php7.4` to "upgrade" the server to a later version of PHP.

(Note, you will also need to configure the server to use the newer version of PHP, but that is outside the scope of your question.)